# `htmlize` not taking CIDER font-locking into account

Tags: org-mode, org-export, font-lock, htmlize

I'm using [`htmlize`](https://melpa.org/#/htmlize) to give Org-mode code blocks syntax highlighting when exported as HTML, but the exported code only captures *some* of the font-locking.

In particular, for [Clojure](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/clojure-mode), it does not capture the extra font-locking from [CIDER](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider).

In my `init.el`, I have:

```el
(with-eval-after-load 'clojure-mode
  (add-hook 'clojure-mode-hook #'cider-mode))
```

So when I have a CIDER connection open, all `clojure-mode` buffers should be getting CIDER font-locking.

When CIDER is **off**, I see:

[image: No CIDER font locking]

When CIDER is **on**, I see:

[image: CIDER font locking]

But either way, the exported HTML only contains font-locking for the **off** case:

```html
(when-let [s (seq coll)]
  (if (chunked-seq? s)
    (let [c (chunk-first s)
(<span style="color: #F0DFAF; font-weight: bold;">when-let</span> [s (seq coll)]
  (<span style="color: #F0DFAF; font-weight: bold;">if</span> (chunked-seq? s)
    (<span style="color: #F0DFAF; font-weight: bold;">let</span> [c (chunk-first s)
          size (int (count c))
          b (chunk-buffer size)]
      (dotimes [i size]
          (chunk-append b (f (.nth c i))))
      (<span style="color: #F0DFAF; font-weight: bold;">dotimes</span> [i size]
```

Why is this? I *assume* `htmlize` works by creating a `clojure-mode` buffer, then converting the font-locking to CSS properties, in which case it *should* capture CIDER's font-locking.